# Loading ip based video stream in flutter iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, avplayer, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing a mobile application in flutter for streaming videos. Some of the streams are ip based and they are not https, but http only. I managed to play these videos in android, but in iOS, it not playing these videos. I think ATS is blocking it in iOS. I tried setting `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES` in `info.plist`, but still it's not working. Is there an alternative  way to play these streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was not due to ATS, but because of flutter video player. Flutter video player had some problem in playing m3u8 streams. Hence I loaded native iOS avplayer and solved the problem.